# CSS: how we can do slide animation in slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple slider where animation between slides is only made by opacity.

I have no idea how I can do slide animation from left to right when the user clicks on the right arrow and on the left arrow from the right to left animation.

Is there any option how we can do it with CSS or we will need to add more javascript?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.mySlides.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Slideshow container -->
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width slides/quotes -->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for.</q>
      <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Next/prev buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Dots/bullets/indicators -->
  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the snippet here.
I just use CSS animations and a little update on javascript and CSS, but the animation itself is managed by CSS animation.

Please note, this is just an idea to manage left and right arrows buttons, you should also edit CSS for dots.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n, n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n, idx) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
    slides[i].classList.remove("from-left");
    slides[i].classList.remove("from-right");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  if (idx === undefined){
    idx=1;
  }
  if (idx < 1) {
    slides[slideIndex-1].classList.add("from-left");
  }else{
    slides[slideIndex-1].classList.add("from-right");
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /*transition: visibility 0s, opacity 5s linear;*/
}

.mySlides.active.from-left {
  visibility: visible;
  display:block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: runLeft;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.001s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.mySlides.active.from-right {
  visibility: visible;
  display:block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: runRight;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.001s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes runLeft {
  0% {
    left:100%;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% { 
    
    left:50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
   }
  100% {
   
    left:0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes runRight {
  0% {
    right:100%;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% { 
    right:50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
   }
  100% {
    right:0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}



/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Slideshow container -->
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width slides/quotes -->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for.</q>
      <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Next/prev buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Dots/bullets/indicators -->
  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, it looks amazing but there is the issue when I click several times after 3 slides it doesn't make animation like in the first 3 slides.

Comment: I cannot understand the issue. Can you please explain better? Do you mean if you click very fast the buttons?

Comment: You click on for example right arrow three times, three times will animation show. After third click fourth animation is not looking like the previous ones.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to replicate on the code snippet. Where have you tested this behavior?

Comment: I have seen other posts on stackoverflow and some guides on other sites. The problem is that Safari won't re-trigger the animation. To solve this behavior some developers suggest to add a delay in the animation. I have managed to work on Safari and tested it with this update. Can you please run the code snippet and check if everything is ok now?